# How to properly integrate workbox into webpack/NPM?

Tags: integration, workbox

I am currently working on a pretty large project, that has many different dependencies spread through many files. To start, I am running NPM and webpack in order to manage most of these dependencies. On the workbox documentation, there are two separate ways for me to integrate this, either via webpack (which is literally just an example) or through NPM. I decided to try to used NPM. I ran the following command:

```
npm install --save-dev workbox-sw
```

This added the workbox-sw to the `package.json` dependency section. However, whenever I try to import using:

```
import Workbox-SW from 'workbox-sw'
```

it gives me the following error:

> Uncaught WorkboxError: An error was thrown by workbox with error code: ;'not-in-sw'

I have tried some other methods, but only naively. The webpack documentation is definitely lackluster, and I would like to avoid install other dependencies in order to get this to run correctly. Some other important notes:

1. I am using Vue.js
2. There are some different components that I have created that interact through routing. I am trying to import into a specific component.

Here is the full error message:

```
    Uncaught WorkboxError: An error was thrown by workbox with error code: ;'not-in-sw'
    at eval (webpack-internal:///259:175:40)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/app.js:2361:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8080/app.js:660:30)
    at fn (http://localhost:8080/app.js:86:20)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///173:3:69)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/app.js:1795:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8080/app.js:660:30)
    at fn (http://localhost:8080/app.js:86:20)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///239:8:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/app.js:2239:1)
WorkboxError    @   workbox-sw.prod.v2.1.1.mjs?efda:155
(anonymous) @   workbox-sw.prod.v2.1.1.mjs?efda:175
(anonymous) @   app.js:2361
__webpack_require__ @   app.js:660
fn  @   app.js:86
(anonymous) @   173:3
(anonymous) @   app.js:1795
__webpack_require__ @   app.js:660
fn  @   app.js:86
(anonymous) @   HomeView.vue?afbe:8
(anonymous) @   app.js:2239
__webpack_require__ @   app.js:660
fn  @   app.js:86
(anonymous) @   index.js?3672:1
(anonymous) @   app.js:1809
__webpack_require__ @   app.js:660
fn  @   app.js:86
(anonymous) @   main.js?1c90:1
(anonymous) @   app.js:1616
__webpack_require__ @   app.js:660
fn  @   app.js:86
(anonymous) @   app.js:2368
__webpack_require__ @   app.js:660
(anonymous) @   app.js:709
(anonymous) @   app.js:712
```

Answer (score 0):

The specific error you're seeing, `not-in-sw`, is due to using the code exposed in the `workbox-sw` library from outside of the `ServiceWorkerGlobalScope`. That would happen if you're, e.g., importing the service worker code into your page as a `<script>` or as a Web Worker.

The best resource I could point you to is the new "[Get Started With Workbox For Webpack](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/get-started/webpack)" guide.